# JS Hint: Functions declared within loops & The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype

Tags: javascript

I was looking for some help in understanding and improving code on some feedback I'm receiving from JSHINT when I run my JavaScript through it I get these errors:

*Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (foodIndex, i, basketItem, addItemToBasket, food)*

for this code -

```
    addToBasket[i].addEventListener("click", e => {
        foodIndex = i;
        if (!basketItem.includes(foodIndex)) {
            basketItem.push(foodIndex);
            addItemToBasket(food[i], i);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Then I get the above warning and:

*The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.*

for code:

```
// show previously stored basket data
let storedBasketItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("foodInBasket")) || {};

for (const key in storedBasketItems) {
    // get corresponding food index
    food.forEach(function (food, i) {
        if (food.name === storedBasketItems[key].name) foodIndex = i;
    });

    if (!basketItem.includes(foodIndex)) {
        basketItem.push(foodIndex);
        food[foodIndex].inBasket = storedBasketItems[key].inBasket;
        updateModal(foodIndex);
    }
}
```

Full example of code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Birrellc/mt1Lrkyq/47)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that this:

```
for (const key in storedBasketItems) {
  // ...
```

should be

```
for (const key in storedBasketItems) {
  if (storedBasketItems.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // ...
```

and that if you use `var` to declare variables, that it has problems inside loops because `var` is function-scoped, not block-scoped. (But you look to be using `const` and `let`, so this isn't a problem; this is a false positive by JSHint.)

Another way to avoid the `in` warning is to iterate over the `Object.entries` of the object instead:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(storedBasketItems)) {
  // do stuff with key and value
}
```

You could also avoid the scope warning by using loops instead of `forEach` callbacks, eg, change:

```
food.forEach(function (food, i) {
```

to

```
for (const [i, food] of food.entries()) {
```

You could also look into [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), which I personally find to be significantly more useful than JSHint when improving code quality.